# Getting org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException;org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException while trying to save entity with JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, many-to-many, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save user data using JpaRepositroy.save(), But getting the following error.

```
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare
> statement; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare
> statement     at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
>   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
>   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
>   at
> org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
>   at
> org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
>   at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.save(Unknown Source)     at
> org.zerhusen.security.service.UserServiceImpl.save(UserServiceImpl.java:22)
>   at
> org.zerhusen.security.controller.RegisterRestController.getAuthenticatedUser(RegisterRestController.java:73)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
> org.zerhusen.security.JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter.java:70)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>   at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare
> statement     at
> org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:72)
>   at
> org.hibernate.id.SequenceGenerator.generateHolder(SequenceGenerator.java:114)
>   at
> org.hibernate.id.SequenceHiLoGenerator.generate(SequenceHiLoGenerator.java:62)
>   at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:101)
>   at
> org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaMergeEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaMergeEventListener.java:56)
>   at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.saveTransientEntity(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:255)
>   at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:235)
>   at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:301)
>   at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170)
>   at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
>   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840)
>   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822)   at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827)    at
> org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.merge(Unknown Source)     at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.merge(Unknown Source)     at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:511)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
>   at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
>   at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   at
> org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>   at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
>   at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>   at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>   ... 101 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: SQL String can not be
> NULL  at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:545)
>   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:513)
>   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:505)
>   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:479)
>   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.<init>(PreparedStatement.java:804)
>   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.PreparedStatement.getInstance(PreparedStatement.java:754)
>   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.clientPrepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1059)
>   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:3155)
>   at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:3062)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.invoke(AbstractCreateStatementInterceptor.java:75)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
>   at
> org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)  at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:87)
>   at
> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)
>   ... 143 more
```

I have set values for all the variables in User entity(id,name,password,firstname,lastname,email,enabled,lastpwdreset,authority id, authority name). So there is no NULL value.

Here is the User entity I want to save :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_seq", sequenceName = "user_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", length = 50, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", length = 100)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 100)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME", length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME", length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "ENABLED")
    @NotNull
    private Boolean enabled;

    @Column(name = "LASTPASSWORDRESETDATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @NotNull
    private Date lastPasswordResetDate;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_AUTHORITY", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHORITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") })
    private List<Authority> authorities;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Boolean getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public List<Authority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(List<Authority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public Date getLastPasswordResetDate() {
        return lastPasswordResetDate;
    }

    public void setLastPasswordResetDate(Date lastPasswordResetDate) {
        this.lastPasswordResetDate = lastPasswordResetDate;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", username=" + username + ", password=" + password + ", firstname=" + firstname
                + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", email=" + email + ", enabled=" + enabled + ", lastPasswordResetDate="
                + lastPasswordResetDate + ", authorities=" + authorities + "]";
    }

}
```

and Authority :

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORITY")
public class Authority {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "authority_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "authority_seq", sequenceName = "authority_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AuthorityName name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    private List<User> users;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public AuthorityName getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(AuthorityName name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Authority [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", users=" + users + "]";
    }

}
```

I think this is because of the many-to-many mapping.I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution.

Edit 
Here is SQL debug

```
    2017-12-18 00:13:13.521[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m19492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [36morg.hibernate.SQL                       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m 
        /* load org.zerhusen.model.security.User */ select
            user0_.id as id1_4_0_,
            user0_.email as email2_4_0_,
            user0_.enabled as enabled3_4_0_,
            user0_.firstname as firstnam4_4_0_,
            user0_.lastpasswordresetdate as lastpass5_4_0_,
            user0_.lastname as lastname6_4_0_,
            user0_.password as password7_4_0_,
            user0_.username as username8_4_0_ 
        from
            user user0_ 
        where
            user0_.id=?
    Hibernate: 
        /* load org.zerhusen.model.security.User */ select
            user0_.id as id1_4_0_,
            user0_.email as email2_4_0_,
            user0_.enabled as enabled3_4_0_,
            user0_.firstname as firstnam4_4_0_,
            user0_.lastpasswordresetdate as lastpass5_4_0_,
            user0_.lastname as lastname6_4_0_,
            user0_.password as password7_4_0_,
            user0_.username as username8_4_0_ 
        from
            user user0_ 
        where
            user0_.id=?
    [2m2017-12-18 00:13:13.522[0;39m [32mTRACE[0;39m [35m19492[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[io-8080-exec-10][0;39m [36mo.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [0]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.BasicFormatterImpl$FormatProcess.<init>(BasicFormatterImpl.java:100)
```

Comment: Why not start by POSTING the SQL statement?!!

Comment: Just guessing; have a look at `AuthorityName` to `String` transformation.

Comment: I would try removing `users` from `Authority` class. And by the way, if you try to save a new user, don't  set explicitly value for `id`.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I replace AuthorityName with String, But that didn't worked. Then I removed users from Authority as @lzagkaretos suggested,But that didn't worked either. Then I replace @ GeneratedValue() and @ SequenceGenerator() with just @ GeneratedValue and IT WORKED. THANK YOU :)